# trying to debug a virgin mobile android 2.3 smart phone

Tags: android

On windows 7, I can debug my android program fine when my acer tablet is connected and I have an active device selected in the run configuration.

If I try to debug it on my Virgine android smart phone (android 2.3), I get a message that says no active compatable AVD's or devices.

my android device is v 2.3 and the project is set up for android 2.2,

also the virgin phone works fine on my mac.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have the drivers installed. Check the manufacturer's website for USB debugging driver, or, if you're feeling adventurous, modify standard Android USB driver to include your device's USB ID (I did it for my Chinese tablet).